# Add Constraint to check value exists in a non-unique composite key column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, constraint, check-constraints

I have the following table, which has a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Seqs(
    SequenceKey nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    UsageSequence smallint NOT NULL,
    col1 bit NOT NULL,
    col2 nvarchar(30) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Seqs PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        SequenceKey ASC,
        UsageSequence ASC
    )
)
```

I'm looking to create the following table, with a 'SequenceKey' column that must only accept values that are present in the 'Seqs' table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sometbl (
    SomeID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Col1 int NOT NULL,
    Col2 nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Col3 nvarchar(30) NULL,
    SequenceKey nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Sometbl PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        SomeID ASC
        )
    )
```

Given that the 'SequenceKey' in the 'Seqs' table is not unique (the primary key uniqueness is reliant on the 'UsageSequence' column), what is the best way to ensure data cannot be added or updated in 'Sometbl' with a 'SequenceKey' value that doesn't exist in the 'Seqs' table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible answer to my own question, this could be achieved by adding a Check constraint with a function such as the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckSequenceKey (@SequenceKey nvarchar(10))
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @retval bit

  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Seqs S WHERE S.SequenceKey = @SequenceKey)
      SET @retval = 1
  ELSE 
      SET @retval = 0

  RETURN @retval
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Sometbl
  ADD CONSTRAINT chkSequenceKey
  CHECK (dbo.CheckSequenceKey(SequenceKey) = 1);
```

**EDIT:**

The Check constraint prevents inserts and updates to the 'Sometbl' table where the new value for 'SequenceKey' is not found within the 'Seqs' table and this is my preference over the use of a trigger.

However, the check constraint doesn't restrict updates to values in the 'SequenceKey' column in the 'Seqs' table or the deletion of entire rows from this table, which could lead to orphaned records in the 'Sometbl' table. Therefore I've taken the below from EzLo's answer to be applied in addition to the check contraint and function for a more complete solution:

- Then for `dbo.Seqs` you can rollback operation that
  attempts to update or delete if the `SequenceKey` is being
  referenced:

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.utrCheckSequenceKeyReferencesOnDelete ON dbo.Seqs
      AFTER DELETE
  AS
  BEGIN

      IF EXISTS (
          SELECT
              'deleted records have a SequenceKey being referenced'
          FROM
              deleted AS D
          WHERE
              EXISTS (SELECT 'the sequence is being referenced' FROM dbo.Sometbl AS S WHERE S.SequenceKey = D.SequenceKey))
      BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Can''t delete SequenceKey being referenced in dbo.Sometbl', 16, 1)
          ROLLBACK
      END

  END

  -------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.utrCheckSequenceKeyReferencesOnUpdate ON dbo.Seqs
      AFTER UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN

      IF UPDATE(SequenceKey) AND EXISTS (
          SELECT
              'updated records have a SequenceKey being referenced'
          FROM
              deleted AS D
          WHERE
              EXISTS (SELECT 'the sequence is being referenced' FROM dbo.Sometbl AS S WHERE S.SequenceKey = D.SequenceKey))
      BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Can''t update SequenceKey being referenced in dbo.Sometbl', 16, 1)
          ROLLBACK
      END

  END
  ```

Comment: My only advice would be to make it a "SELECT TOP (1) 1".

Comment: Using a `CHECK` will only validate the row on insertion, won't prevent the `Seqs` record from being deleted or updated.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use triggers to check the integrity. Remember you will have to check for operations on both tables since it's possible to delete referenced rows from `dbo.Seqs`.

- First trigger on `dbo.Sometbl` will rollback if inserted or updated
  value does not exist on `dbo.Seqs`:

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.utrValidateSequenceKey ON dbo.Sometbl
      AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN

      IF EXISTS (
          SELECT
              'new or updated records have an invalid SequenceKey'
          FROM
              inserted AS I
          WHERE
              NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'the sequence does not exist' FROM dbo.Seqs AS S WHERE I.SequenceKey = S.SequenceKey))
      BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Invalid SequenceKey detected on dbo.Sometbl', 16, 1)
          ROLLBACK
      END

  END
  ```
- Then for `dbo.Seqs` you can rollback operation that
  attempts to update or delete if the `SequenceKey` is being
  referenced:

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.utrCheckSequenceKeyReferencesOnDelete ON dbo.Seqs
      AFTER DELETE
  AS
  BEGIN

      IF EXISTS (
          SELECT
              'deleted records have a SequenceKey being referenced'
          FROM
              deleted AS D
          WHERE
              EXISTS (SELECT 'the sequence is being referenced' FROM dbo.Sometbl AS S WHERE S.SequenceKey = D.SequenceKey))
      BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Can''t delete SequenceKey being referenced in dbo.Sometbl', 16, 1)
          ROLLBACK
      END

  END

  -------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TRIGGER dbo.utrCheckSequenceKeyReferencesOnUpdate ON dbo.Seqs
      AFTER UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN

      IF UPDATE(SequenceKey) AND EXISTS (
          SELECT
              'updated records have a SequenceKey being referenced'
          FROM
              deleted AS D
          WHERE
              EXISTS (SELECT 'the sequence is being referenced' FROM dbo.Sometbl AS S WHERE S.SequenceKey = D.SequenceKey))
      BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Can''t update SequenceKey being referenced in dbo.Sometbl', 16, 1)
          ROLLBACK
      END

  END
  ```